# how to get event of pager click in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am trying to get event bottom circles event (called pager click ).

I am using this link

> http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionSlideBox/

I want to move on  that slide at which circle user click (on which pager button click)

here is my code

> http://plnkr.co/edit/100pA0XAi586oIwVIxyy?p=preview

```
<ion-slide-box>
  <ion-slide-pager ng-click="doSomething($slideIndex)"></ion-slide-pager>
  <ion-slide>1</ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>2</ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>3</ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

**Update:**

I got now event but it is not moving to that slide here is my updated code
http://plnkr.co/edit/100pA0XAi586oIwVIxyy?p=preview

```
    <ion-slide-box pager-click="doSomething(index)">
  <ion-slide>1</ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>2</ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>3</ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

**javascript**

```
$scope.doSomething=function(tem){
    alert(tem)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calling `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide()` on pager click

SCRIPT

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
  $scope.myActiveSlide = 1;
  $scope.success=[];
  $http.get('defult.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.success=data;
    console.log(data)
  }).error(function(data){

  })
  $scope.doSomething=function(tem){
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(tem);
    //alert(tem);

  }

});
```

Comment: could you please use plunker